# How to add orderBy() with where() of Find()?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

**How to add an orderBy() with a where condition?**

```
$floor_data = Floors::find()->where(['building_id' => $id])->orderBy->(['floor_no' => SORT_DESC])->all();
```

This is giving me a syntax error saying

> syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: remove -> after orderBy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra `->` caused the error:

```
$floor_data = Floors::find()
    ->where(['building_id' => $id])
    //   Remove ↓↓   
    // ->orderBy->(['floor_no' => SORT_DESC])
    ->orderBy(['floor_no' => SORT_DESC])
    ->all();
```